# Watir-webdriver How to click first element by class in a carousel of links?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I have a carousel of links all with the same class however some of them cannot be seen (not visible) due to how the carousel works.

The code I have tried using is:

```
browser.link(:class, "nochevron").first.click
```

However I keep getting an error saying .first is un-defined even though I have seen others using it.

My question is how to click the first link in a carousel of links that have the same class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change `link` to `links` or `as`:

```
browser.links(:class => "nochevron").first.click
```

or

```
browser.as(:class => "nochevron").first.click
```

Comment: Changed it to links and it worked, so simple yet so effective.  Thanks!